# So, Unity and Vs CODE are not working together, I have updated all everything, Downloaded every version and its not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

Ok, Im tryna make a 2D game in unity because im bored, and everything else is fine, Sprites, Physics, But when I try to make a new script it tells me too re download vs or smthing and this has been happening for WEEKS and I just really want to get this too work, And yes Ik i have asked this before but it didnt work.

Comment: Ever since Unity announced the plan to retire its MonoDevelop IDE, the options are clear on the table and VSCode is probably the last one you should consider, https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/01/05/discontinuing-support-for-monodevelop-unity-starting-in-unity-2018-1/

Comment: I've tried VS Community too with no luck

Comment: With VS Community, what's the exact error message? Edit your question to include more details (even screen shots are better than none).

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily change your IDE:

Go to **Preferences -> external tools -> and change the default editor to visual studio code**

There is an assets that you can download in the assets manager.

If this does not work, just open your scripts by opening the folder in VS Code.